# Restrict kinds of heads when dealing with level concept

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, map, data-structures

```
In[1]  Map[(# + 7) &, {a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, {2}]
Out[1]  {a, 10 (7 + b), {7 + c, 7 + d}, e}
```

But I want feature like *ListMap* :

```
In[2]  ListMap[(# + 7) &, {a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, {2}]
Out[2]  {a, 3b, {7 + c, 7 + d}, e}
```

(* +7 to every level 2 object. But when determining level, ignore all head except List. *)

The concept of **level** is very closely related to 'Head', more precisely, **'all kinds of Heads'**.
Can we restrict kinds of heads temporarily?

For example, can we do somethig like

**'of all heads, only List is regarded as an effective head, when dealing with level concept, only for this time'.**

There are many built-in symbols containing 'level' as their arguments. Map,Outer,Apply,...Ideally I hope there exist an original method which works for all such built-in symbols.

Comment: `Replace[{a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, x_List :> x + 7, {1}]`

Comment: Here's a clarifying question: should `ListMap` have to encounter `List`s all the way down? For instance, in `{c, f[{a}, b]}`, listmapping `h` over all lists at level 3 naively would produce `{c, f[{h[a]}, b]}`; but it would have to "go through" the head `f` to get there. Should listmap be defined such that it can only "go through" `List` heads when trying to reach the level it's seeking, or not?

Comment: Thank you @thorimur. My concept about ListMap is : there is no level 2,3 object for {c, f[{h[a]}, b]}.  In fact I was constructing ListMap but wasn't considering such case. The first thing to do may be atomization of all the other heads.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for using different heads and levels:

```
customMap[fn_, arr_, heads_List, level_] := 
 Replace[arr, Alternatives @@ (Pattern[x, Blank[#]] & /@ heads) -> fn[x], level]

customMap[(# + 3) &, {a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, {List}, {1}]

(*Out: {a, 3 b, {3 + c, 3 + d}, e} *)
```

#### Solution 1

Using `customMap`:

```
ListMap[fn_, arr_, level_] := customMap[fn, arr, {List}, level]

ListMap[(# + 3) &, {a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, {1}]

(*Out: {a, 3 b, {3 + c, 3 + d}, e} *)
```

#### Solution 2

Using `Replace`:

```
ListMap[fn_, arr_, level_] := Replace[arr, x_List -> fn[x], level]

ListMap[(# + 3) &, {a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, {1}]

(*Out: {a, 3 b, {3 + c, 3 + d}, e} *)
```

---

If you want to apply to all elements of a list at a specific level:

```
ListMap[fn_, arr_, level_] := Replace[arr, x_List :> fn /@ x, level]


ListMap[{#, x} &, {a, b, c}, {0}]

(*Out: {{a, x}, {b, x}, {c, x}} *)


ListMap[(# + 7) &, {a, 3 b, {c, d}, e}, {1}]

(*Out: {a, 3 b, {7 + c, 7 + d}, e} *)
```

Also, levels start at 0, you can change the function definition but I think it's better to be consistent with other functions.

Comment: Thanks for sincere interest but my idea was misrepresented or you misunderstood something. The output of ListMap[{#, x} &, {a, b, c}, {1}] must be {{a,x},{b,x},{c,x}}. But the functions you presented doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @imidak I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of checking the heads "on the way down", and only mapping through expressions with head `head`; I tried to account for Mathematica's usual level specification, but didn't manage to account for negative level specification (which proceeds from the innermost level).

```
(* Exact levels {n}: *)

headMap[f_, expr_, head_, {0}] := f[expr]

headMap[f_, expr_, head_, {level_Integer}] := 
 Replace[expr, x_head :> Map[headMap[f, #, head, {level - 1}] &, x, {1}]] /; level > 0

(* Range of levels {n1, n2}: *)

headMap[f_, expr_, head_, {n1_Integer, n2 : (_Integer | Infinity)}] :=
 Which[
  n2 == 0, f[expr],
  n1 == 0, 
   Construct[f, Replace[expr, x_head :> Map[headMap[f, #, head, {0, n2 - 1}] &, x, {1}]]],
  True, Replace[expr, x_head :> Map[headMap[f, #, head, {n1, n2} - 1] &, x, {1}]]
 ] /; n2 >= n1 >= 0

(* Levels given by an integer n or Infinity, i.e. levels 1 through n *)

headMap[f_, expr_, head_, 0] := f[expr]

headMap[f_, expr_, head_, Infinity] := headMap[f, expr, head, {1, Infinity}]

headMap[f_, expr_, head_, level : _Integer] := headMap[f, expr, head, {1, level}] /; level > 0
```

Note: this could be generalized to accept patterns matching heads instead of explicit heads by using, say, `x_ :> Map[...] /; MatchQ[Head[x], head]` everywhere instead.

And then we can define

```
ListMap[f_, expr_, level_] := headMap[f, expr, List, level]
```

Examples:

```
ListMap[{#, x} &, {a, b, c}, {1}]

(* Output: {{a, x}, {b, x}, {c, x}} *)

ListMap[{#, x} &, {a, 3 b, c}, Infinity]

(* Output: {{a, x}, {3 b, x}, {c, x}} *)

ListMap[f, {e, d, {a, {b, x}, g[c, {d, h}]}}, {3}]

(* Output: {e, d, {a, {f[b], f[x]}, g[c, {d, h}]}} *)

ListMap[f, {e, d, {a, {b, x}, g[c, {d, h}]}}, Infinity]

(* Output: {f[e], f[d], f[{f[a], f[{f[b], f[x]}], f[g[c, {d, h}]]}]} *)

ListMap[f, {e, d, {a, {b, x}, g[c, {d, h}]}}, {2, 3}]

(* Output: {e, d, {f[a], f[{f[b], f[x]}], f[g[c, {d, h}]]}} *)
```

As you can check, these are the analogues of what `Map` does with the corresponding level specifications, but only ever "maps through" heads that are `List`!